# Javascript: When reinitializing an object does it inherit its previous properties?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

If say, you have something like this:

```
var foo = function(bar){
    this.bar = bar;
}
```

And initialize it like

```
var myFoo = new foo("bar");
```

When it is re-initialized like

```
myFoo = new foo("bar2");
```

is it able to read the value of foo before it is overwritten?

Comment: That’s not the right way to construct an object; you have to use `new`, as in `new foo("bar")`. Otherwise, `this` will be bound to the global object if you’re not in strict mode. (Be in [**strict mode**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)!)

Comment: right, then you can access the property `bar` using `myFoo.bar`

Comment: Once you’re using the constructor correctly, the answer is “no”. `myFoo = new foo("bar2");` creates a new object and assigns `myFoo` to point to it; there is no reinitialization, just reassignment. You could modify your constructor to accept a previous object, for use like `new foo("bar2", myFoo)`, but whether that’s a good idea depends on what you’re trying to accomplish.

Comment: No. myFoo is assigned to a new object.